# Gave nobody user owner ship of directory, now missing. Can I revert back by just doing the opposite command?

Tags: linux, wordpress, cpanel, whm, file-ownership

I upgraded my server from easy apache 3 to 4 and gained some permission issues, I ran:

`chown -R nobody /home/myuser/public_html`

in the server, which corrected this, now that directory is no where to be seen on cpanel but the site is still live.

Can I put the directory back but simply using:

`chown -R myuser /home/nobody/public_html when ssh'd in as root?`

Self managed server so my host won't help me.

Thanks Brad

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the permission using below command.

chown -R myuser /home/myuser/public_html